# Problem with clicking select2 dropdownlist in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, jquery-select2

I write tests using selenium with python. There is a problem with a dropdown list.

I tried using direct click and also javascript executescript methods but none of them worked. I used selenium IDE to find out id, css, xpath etc. So there is more than one options and I tried them all.

```
#select_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#select2-2v7k-container")

#select_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".col-md-12")

#select_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_id("select2-2v7k-container")

#select_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_id("select2-t2zd-container")

select_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='select2-2v7k-container']")

self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", select_btn)

#select_btn.click()
```

Here is the elements part (It is in-house product so there is no public url)

```
<span _ngcontent-c3="" class="col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
<dashboard-saved-reports-select-component _ngcontent-c3="" _nghost-c5=""><select _ngcontent-c5="" aria-hidden="true" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-control select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%" tabindex="-1">
<option _ngcontent-c5="" value="-1">Select A saved Report</option>
<optgroup _ngcontent-c5="" label="Reports 1">
<!----><option _ngcontent-c5="" value="447">options1
</option><option _ngcontent-c5="" value="457">options2
</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup _ngcontent-c5="" label="Reports 2">
<!----><option _ngcontent-c5="" value="1020">options1
</option><option _ngcontent-c5="" value="1013">option2
</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup _ngcontent-c5="" label="Reports 3">
</option><option _ngcontent-c5="" value="1035">denemeee
</option><option _ngcontent-c5="" value="1033">deneme-rapor
</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup _ngcontent-c5="" label="Reports 4">
<!----><option _ngcontent-c5="" value="1032">dasd
</option><option _ngcontent-c5="" value="1025">deneeeeee
</option><option _ngcontent-c5="" value="1014">deneme
</option>
</optgroup>
</select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 100%;">
<span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="select2-cawo-container">
<span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-cawo-container" title="Select A saved Report">Select A saved Report</span>
<span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span>
<span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
</dashboard-saved-reports-select-component>
</span>
```

Is there another method or workaround to detect and open dropdown list. I found out some javascript method to make visible dropdown but it didn't worked.

Comment: Can you add html or better share the url.

Comment: Sorry it is an in-house product so there is no public url.

Comment: In the code snippet you provided there is no span tag with the id `select2-2v7k-container`. Plus if you want to open a dropdown list you need to click `select` tag

Comment: I took id, xpath, css etc. from Selenium IDE and I put code directly from the page. I don't know why it is different

Comment: is the drop down inside iframe did you checked that?

Comment: There is no tag for iframe but I am not sure about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the id part and realized that id is changing in each refresh.
@id='select2-**2v7k**-container'.

I find out I can use the arrow part of the dropdown. It is working only once but it is enough for my test case.

```
 #select_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".select2-selection__arrow") 
 select_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span/span[2]")
```